# add matriculation number to letter

Tags: letters, letterhead

While writing a letter to university I need to give my matriculation number. Is there a way to include this into the Letter head like

```
\setkomavar{customer}[\customername]{DE-112233}
```

I whish to get something like "matriculation number: DE-112233" as output.
Is there a way to define own komavar?

Thanks!

My code is like:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    parskip=full,
    paper=A4,   
    fromalign=right,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true, 
    version=last,
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Myadress 1\\12345 Foo}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 123 456789}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{my.mail@foo.com}
\setkomavar{place}{Bar-place}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{subject}{interesting letter}

\setkomavar{customer}[\customername]{DE-112233} % <---- I would like to rename this or something like that

\begin{letter}{
    Some addresse\\
    not my street 2\\
    54321 Town
}

\opening{Hello everyone,}

Loreß "`ipsum"'  sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus euismod nibh. Nulla condimentum, odio in vehicula bibendum, tellus libero varius sapien, vel aliquam elit mauris ut leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla vitae dapibus felis, ut euismod lectus.
 
Vestibulum at auctor urna, in iaculis lectus. Nullam vitae magna metus. Praesent lacinia massa ac lobortis ullamcorper. Vestibulum laoreet, ligula ut tincidunt auctor, ligula lacus accumsan lectus, vitae aliquet justo diam et risus. Etiam suscipit magna vel velit tristique, quis egestas justo aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lacus, ac nulla.

\closing{Greetings}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reuse one of the komavar and replace the name to "matriculation number".
For example the Fax Variable:

add to the \documentclass[]

```
fromfax=true
```

and change the name

```
\setkomavar{fromfax}[matriculation number: ]{DE-112233}
```

You can find this and more information in the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#%5B0,%7B%22name%22:%22Fit%22%7D%5D) on page 196.